# Stuck on Black Screen after Ubuntu 20.04 LTS upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

So, I decided to upgrade Ubuntu to 22.04 LTS. The installation/upgrade process went flawlessly. Everything seemed to be fine until I was prompted to restart my computer. Now it will not boot into Ubuntu (Black Screen).

There's nothing else but Ubuntu installed (No dual boot - trying to avoid Microsoft).

I have a Gigabyte B450M DS3H motherboard, an AMD Ryzen 7 2700x Threadripper CPU, 32G RAM (Kingston HyperX HX424C15FB2K2/16 x 2 - the motherboard wouldn't start with 4x16G RAM), and a PNY GeForce GTX 1060 6B graphics card.

Once I restart, I see the graphics card and the BIOS splash screens then I see a bunch of prompts from Ubuntu but I can't read fast enough all the issues before the screen turns black, then the monitor goes to sleep.

The 2 errors I see:

```
[...] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[...] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

[Edit 1]
Pressing ctrl-alt-F3 at the black screen brought up TTY which allowed me to login using my credentials.

[Edit 2]
At the prompt, I typed:

```
:~$ inxi -Gx --display
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/inxi line 13826.
Graphics:
   Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] vendor: PNY driver: nvidia v: 515.65.01 bus-ID: 06:00.0
   Display: server: X.org v:1.21.1.3 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1 driver: X: loaded: N/A unloaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia note: X driver n/a tty: 128x48 s-res: 640x480~Hz
   OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 v:4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.65.01 direct renderer: Yes
:~$ sudo lshw -c video
   *-display
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
      version: a1
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list from
      configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
      resources: irq:51 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
   *-graphics
      product: EFI VGA
      physical id: 1
      logical name: /dev/fb0
      compatibilities: fb
      configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

[Edit 3]
Disabled the ultra-fast boot to enable my peripherals to enter the GRUB.
Added nomodeset:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

It did not change anything.

Note: I had to disable the ultra-fast boot from the BIOS by disconnecting my SSD (my keyboard was disabled during boot - Fast boot is correct though - use an old PS/2 keyboard too).

[Edit 4]

```
demond@demond-B450M-DS3H:~$ startx
xauth: file /home/demond/.Xauthorithy does not exist

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux demond-B450M-DS3H 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=15c3a740-13ef-4c8e-83c1-ef1e168eee77 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting, (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, (WW) Warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/demond/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Tue Aug 23 17:18:27 2022
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

demond@demond-B450M-DS3H:~$
```

[Edit 5]
Disabled nouveau graphics driver.
Purged Nvidia Drivers and installed Nvidia-driver-510
Purged Nvidia Drivers again and reinstalled Nvidia-driver-515 (recommended)

So far, nothing has fixed the issue.

[Edit 6]
Purged Nvidia Drivers again and installed Nvidia-driver-470 and it finally worked!

Conclusion:
With my hardware configuration, only these software configuration works:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS / Kernel 5.4 / NVidia Driver **515**
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / Kernel 5.15 / NVidia Driver **470**

But why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138753/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-emond-stuck-on-black-screen-after-ubuntu-20-04).